# Consulta usando Eloquent multiplos campos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

tudo bem?

Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês para montar uma consulta mais "elegante" no Laravel.
Atualmente tenho o seguinte cenário.

Preciso checar se um cliente já está cadastrado no meu banco de dados.
Para isso eu posso utilizar até 3 condições, sendo pelo:
- email
- telefone fixo
- celular

Só que esses 3 campos muitas vezes não vem preenchida, ou seja, pode ser que o cliente informou apenas campo, ou até mesmo 2 campos..

Porém ai que começa a ficar complicado.
Por exemplo, se eu tenho apenas 1 campo é fácil, apenas usar o "where", porém quando tenho dois campos preciso usar o "orWhere"...

Bom, hoje eu fiz um código que está FUNCIONANDO, porém, eu achei extremamente feio... gostaria de saber que forma eu poderia montar mais elegante isto.

```
$customer = Customer::select('*');

        $secondFilter = false;
        $filter = false;
        if (!empty($this->lead['email'])) {
            $secondFilter = true;
            $filter = true;
            $customer = $customer->where('email', $this->lead['email']);
        }

        if (!empty($this->lead['cpf_cnpj'])) {
            $filter = true;
            if ($secondFilter) {
                $customer = $customer->orWhere('cpf_cnpj', $this->lead['cpf_cnpj']);
            } else {
                $customer = $customer->where('cpf_cnpj', $this->lead['cpf_cnpj']);
            }
            $secondFilter = true;
        }

        if (!empty($this->lead['phone'])) {
            $filter = true;
            if ($secondFilter) {
                $customer = $customer->where('phone', $this->lead['phone']);
            } else {
                $customer = $customer->orWhere('phone', $this->lead['phone']);
            }
            $secondFilter = true;
        }

        if (!empty($this->lead['mobile'])) {
            $filter = true;
            if ($secondFilter) {
                $customer = $customer->where('mobile', $this->lead['mobile']);
            } else {
                $customer = $customer->orWhere('mobile', $this->lead['mobile']);
            }
        }

        $customer = $filter ? $customer->first() : false;

        $newRegister = false;
        $this->lead['action_lead'] = 'UPDATE';
        if (!$customer) {
            $newRegister = true;
            $customer = new Customer;
            $this->lead['action_lead'] = 'NEW';
        }

        if ($this->lead['company_id']) {
            $customer->company_id = $this->lead['company_id'];
        }

        if ($this->lead['name'] && $newRegister) {
            $customer->name = $this->lead['name'];
        }

        //update name for differnte lead calltracking
        if ($this->lead['name']) {
            $customer->name = $this->lead['name'];
        }

        if (isset($this->lead['city']) && !empty($this->lead['city'])) {
            $customer->city = $this->lead['city'];
        }

        if (isset($this->lead['state']) && !empty($this->lead['state'])) {
            $customer->state = $this->lead['state'];
        }

        if ($this->lead['email'] && !empty($this->lead['email'])) {
            $customer->email = $this->lead['email'];
        }

        if ($this->lead['cpf_cnpj'] && !empty($this->lead['cpf_cnpj'])) {
            $customer->cpf_cnpj = $this->lead['cpf_cnpj'];
        }

        if ($this->lead['phone'] && !empty($this->lead['phone'])) {
            $customer->phone = $this->lead['phone'];
        }

        if (isset($this->lead['mobile']) && !empty($this->lead['mobile'])) {
            $customer->mobile = $this->lead['mobile'];
        }

        $customer->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $customer->save();

        $this->customer = $customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

n entendi bem o `$filter` e `$secondFilter`...

```
$customer = new Customer();

// Se tem campo email busca pelo cliente com o email
if (isset($this->lead['email'])) {
    $customer->where('email', $this->lead['email']);
}

// Se tem campo cpf/cnpj busca pelo cliente com o cpf/cnpj
if (isset($this->lead['cpf_cnpj'])) {
    $customer->where('cpf_cnpj', $this->lead['cpf_cnpj']);
}

// Se tem campo telefone busca pelo cliente com o telefone
if (isset($this->lead['phone'])) {
    $customer->where('phone', $this->lead['phone']);
}

// Se tem campo celular busca pelo cliente com o celular
if (isset($this->lead['mobile'])) {
    $customer->where('mobile', $this->lead['mobile']);
}

/**
 * Tenta acessar o primeiro cliente com as
 * informações preenchidas, senão, cria um novo.
 */
$customer = $customer->firstOrCreate($this->lead);
```

se as colunas no db forem iguais aos nomes dos campos NÃO é necessário atribuir os valores manualmente:

```
$customer->name = $this->lead['name'];
```

a ideia é +- essa, modifique conforme sua necessidade.

consulte a documentação para mais informações

Comment: A variavel Filter e SecondFilter me ajuda por que eu preciso usar a condição OR, ou seja, da maneira q voce montou todas as condições precisam ser iguais, porém, eu preciso utilizar a condicão OR caso alguma seja verdadeira. E como citei no inicio, pode ter situações que apenas o CPF_CNPJ seja preehcido, ou Email, ou pode ter os 2 valores, enfim... usar apenas o where nao resolve o problema por que uma OU outra condição pode ter dados.